# Kotlin callback immediate callback from an if statement

Tags: kotlin

This smells funny because of the two calls to startSync():

```
override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    if (null == dataSnapshot.value) {
        aThing.putAll(defaultConfig)
        dbRef.setValue(botState) { _, _ -> startSync() }
    } else {
        startSync()
    }
}
```

Is there a Kotlin friendly way of saying "If X then do Y with callback Z(), otherwise do nothing with immediate callback Z()"? But without having to have Z() twice.

I'm coming from JavaScript, where a `Promise.resolve().then...` would have fit the bill.

Comment: You can do this (e.g. by creating a local variable containing a lambda that does `startSync()`), but it won't be any shorter or clearer than your current code.

Comment: So sayeth yole!  Ok, will stick with what I have.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't like to argue with @yole, after all he is the author of idioms in Kotlin.

But if you really like something JavaScript like, you could do something like this:

```
dataSnapshot.value.let {
    if (it == null) {
        ::startSync
    }
    else {
        startSync()
        null
    }
}?.let {
    aThing.putAll(defaultConfig)
    dbRef.setValue(botState) { _, _ ->  it() }
}
```

But as you can see, it's not shorter than your version, and actually much more confusing.

Sometimes, imperative way is the right way, I assume.

Another way is to use `with` and method reference:

```
with(::startSync) {
    if (dataSnapshot.value == null) {
        aThing.putAll(defaultConfig)
        dbRef.setValue(botState) { _, _ ->  this() }
    }
    else {
        this()   
    }
}
```